# Is there a website widget or javascript library that turns any Bitcoin address into a clickable widget?

Tags: javascript

Was wondering is there a javascript widget or library that turns any BTC address on a website into a popup QR code on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a QR code for any bitcoin address using Google's QR code maker:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=bitcoin:[your-bitcoin-address-here]

Just point to that as the img src and you'll get something that looks like this:

[image]

Note this address is used by a lot of tests as the private key is literally "1".

Comment: how do you also add in an amount into the QR code?

Comment: Yes, add ?amount=[amount here] to the url

Answer (score 0):

Btcwidget.com allows you to create custom widgets like this with your address.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great browser extention that finds a bitcoin address anywhere on the page including in the head. It can track your browsing time on each website with a btc address and then you can designate tip amounts to be paid to that site every certain period of time by your history. 
http://protip.is/